# Quantmod GetQuote from Yahoo not working

Tags: r, quantmod

I have this function working everyday without problem until today:

```
RetrieveVolume <- function(x) {
     x <- as.character(x)
     Volume_Ind <- (getQuote(x, what = yahooQF("Volume"))[, "Volume"])
}

Short_Sell_Data3 <- lapply(Short_Sell_Data2$V1, RetrieveVolume)


head(Short_Sell_Data2$V1)
   [1] 0001.HK 0002.HK 0003.HK 0004.HK 0005.HK 0006.HK 582 Levels: 0001.HK 0002.HK 0003.HK 0004.HK 0005.HK 0006.HK 0008.HK 0010.HK 0011.HK 0012.HK 0014.HK 0016.HK 0017.HK 0019.HK 0020.HK 0023.HK ... 7341.HK
```

Am i doing something incorrectly please ?

Comment: What were you expecting to see? And what code generated `Short_Sell_Data2` ?

Comment: works fine on my computer. Which version of R are you using? And more importantly what is the error message you are getting?